# Get partial result if terminating function python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am using multiprocessing to stop a function if it does not complete in a set amount of time.

Here is my code:

```
def worker(number):
     result = []
     for i in range(number):
         x = do_things(i) #this can take a long time
         result.append(x)
     return result

p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(random_number,))
p.start()
p.join(10) # Will timeout after 10 seconds
```

Then to kill it if it hasn't finished yet

```
if p.is_alive():
    p.terminate()
    p.join()
    print('killed process because it took too long')
else:
    p.join()
    print('process finished')
```

Now inside of the function that takes a long time, values are being appended to a list, and I want to get that list in the state it is in regardless of whether or not the function has finished.

I̶ ̶h̶a̶v̶e̶ ̶t̶r̶i̶e̶d̶ ̶u̶s̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶a̶ ̶s̶h̶a̶r̶e̶d̶ ̶a̶r̶r̶a̶y̶ ̶a̶n̶d̶ ̶a̶p̶p̶e̶n̶d̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶i̶t̶ ̶i̶n̶s̶i̶d̶e̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶f̶u̶n̶c̶t̶i̶o̶n̶,̶ ̶b̶u̶t̶ ̶t̶h̶i̶s̶ ̶d̶o̶e̶s̶ ̶n̶o̶t̶ ̶w̶o̶r̶k̶ ̶w̶h̶e̶n̶ ̶I̶ ̶k̶i̶l̶l̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶p̶r̶o̶c̶e̶s̶s̶.̶

Here is what I tried, and I meant shared dictionary, not array:

```
def worker(number, dct):
     for i in range(number):
         x = do_things(i) #this can take a long time
         dct[i] = x

dct = {}
p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(random_number, dct,))
p.start()
p.join(10) # Will timeout after 10 seconds

if p.is_alive():
    p.terminate()
    p.join()
    print(dct.values())
    print('killed process because it took too long')
else:
    p.join()
    print(dct.values())
    print('process finished')
```

Comment: "I have tried using a shared array" how did you do this?

Comment: The answer you are looking for is likely a queue and found in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=multiprocessing#exchanging-objects-between-processes).

Comment: Updated question

Comment: Using a `dict` that you put on the stack in `__main__` will not let you access changes to it from another process. Each process essentially _reimports_ `__main__`, so it just gets `dct = {}` which was empty.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a shared array from the `multiprocessing` module

```
import multiprocessing
from time import sleep
import random, math

def worker(number, shared_arr):
    for i in range(number):
        x = do_things(i)
        shared_arr[i] = x

def do_things(n):
    sleep(random.randint(1,2))
    return math.sqrt(n)

arr = multiprocessing.Array('d', 20)

random_number = random.randint(1,20)
p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(random_number, arr,))
p.start()
# Will timeout after 10 seconds
p.join(10)

if p.is_alive():
    p.terminate()
    p.join()
    print(arr[:])
    print('killed process because it took too long')
else:
    p.join()
    print(arr[:])
    print('process finished')
```

I slightly modified your example to simulate your problem. `arr` is the shared array, an object of `multiprocessing.Array` type. To initialize it, it needs the type it is going to store (here `'d'` for double) and the size. Since the maximum number of iterations here will be 20, the array size is also set to 20. The process fills the array in the function until it is stopped and the resulting array `arr` has non-zero entries until that point, remaining, not computed entries being zeros.

Comment: How can I store a `dict` in this array?

Comment: I think the only way would be to turn the `dict` into a `class`. See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Array)  - there are two "shareables" - scalar and a container used here. And they are both limited to C-style types. So you could have a class where one member is the key and the second is the value, then make an array of such classes. Or if I understood well, a class with an array of keys and an array of values representing a single `dict` that you'd want to store. My guess is that those too have to be C-types.

Comment: If you'd like, I can include that code, it's actually interesting. But I'm not sure if by the rules we shouldn't open a new thread.

Comment: I have asked a question here, you might like to answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73412706/python-how-to-get-partial-data-from-the-function-in-multiprocessing

Comment: I saw it the other day but I have some questions before I try answering. I'll post them there now.